# How to STANDALONE execute the following bitbake script in DISTRO="poky" context?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I created the following bitbake script (kind of), but I would like to execute it independently in DISTRO="poky" context:

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/user/YOCTO/oe_core_embedded/poky/meta \
  /home/user/YOCTO/oe_core_embedded/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/user/YOCTO/oe_core_embedded/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  "

for layer in ${BBLAYERS}; do
        cd $layer
        echo -n "$(basename $layer) = "  >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/gitinfo
        git rev-parse HEAD >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/gitinfo
done
```

Explicitly, I do NOT want this script to be part of any recipe .bb, NOT at all?!

How I can do execution of this script standalone?

Thank you,
*nobody*

Answer (score 0):

For me, what you are trying to do is pretty much identical to buildinfo feature?

If you add

```
 INHERIT += "image-buildinfo"
```

to your conf file, you will have those info in /etc/build file.

See https://mender.io/blog/build-info-yocto-2 for more information for example.

If you want to do a standalone script, you can inspire you from poky/scripts/*.py for instance.

Comment: Hello Nayfe. What you wrote here I already knew. To prove it, there is also INHERIT += "image-buildhistory", which already (on the host) contains the full info I requested. And YES, I can write the simple bash script to retrieve this info, since I am beginner with Python. Here is one NOT (per say) "politically" correct question: environment being - bitbake written in Python. In my genesis I asked could I execute standalone bitbake script (shown) in bash or python CLI xterm context, and if yes, how??? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, what bother me is your sentance:
"I do NOT want this script to be part of any recipe .bb"

Bitbake is based on recipes, so it will be hard to create bitbake script without recipe, right?

For me, shell script is acceptable, I'm not sure what you really want to do? sorry.

Comment: Nayfe, here is the deal: there is a bitbake context in the following directory: .../poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake. This one sets the environment to work on recipes. I would like to have addendum to command: source oe-init-build-env, which in addition to bitbake sets bitbake-script context, so I can execute standalone/independent bitbake-script scripts (as bash scripts, for example). Thank you.